# SQL select from date ranges

Tags: mysql, date-range

I have a table of RADIUS session records that includes start time, stop time, and MAC address. I have a requirement to collect a list of users that were online during two time ranges. I believe I'm getting a list of all users online during the time ranges with the following query:

```
SELECT s_session_id, s_start_time, s_stop_time, s_calling_station_id
FROM sessions
WHERE (
  ("2015-10-01 08:00:00" BETWEEN s_start_time AND s_stop_time OR "2015-10-01 08:30:00" BETWEEN s_start_time AND s_stop_time)
  OR
  ("2015-10-01 12:00:00" BETWEEN s_start_time AND s_stop_time OR "2015-10-01 12:30:00" BETWEEN s_start_time AND s_stop_time)
)
ORDER BY s_start_time;
```

But the next step, isolating details for only those users online during *both* periods, is eluding me. The closest I get is adding

```
GROUP BY s_calling_station_id HAVING COUNT(s_calling_station_id) > 1
```

but that doesn't provide me with all the session details.

Fiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1df471/1

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: I don't take it personal ;) By the way, I find your question quite interesting, and I'm glad you've got a good answer (I was working on a very similar approach, but Barmar was faster) If you want to see my approach, [here's the SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1df471/39).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this question already has an accepted answer, I'd like to add this one (it avoids duplicates and pulls the data from the sessions table of all sessions that fulfill the condition):

First, create a table that holds the filtered data (the MAC addresses that have connections on both intervals:

```
create table temp_sessions
select s1.s_calling_station_id
     , if(@t1_1 between s1.s_start_time and s1.s_stop_time or @t1_2 between  s1.s_start_time and s1.s_stop_time, s1.s_session_id, null) as s_1
     , if(@t2_1 between s2.s_start_time and s2.s_stop_time or @t2_2 between  s2.s_start_time and s2.s_stop_time, s2.s_session_id, null) as s_2
from -- I use user variables because it will make easier to modify the time intervals if needed
     (select @t1_1 := '2015-10-01 08:00:00', @t1_2 := '2015-10-01 08:30:00'
           , @t2_1 := '2015-10-01 12:00:00', @t2_2 := '2015-10-01 12:30:00') as init
   , sessions as s1
     inner join sessions as s2 
             on s1.s_calling_station_id = s2.s_calling_station_id
            and s1.s_session_id != s2.s_session_id
having s_1 is not null and s_2 is not null;
```

And now, simply use this table to get what you need:

```
select sessions.*
from sessions
     inner join (
        select s_calling_station_id, s_1 as s_session_id
        from temp_sessions
        union
        select s_calling_station_id, s_2 as s_session_id
        from temp_sessions
     ) as a using (s_calling_station_id, s_session_id);
```

[Here's the SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94ab3/1)

Comment: Thanks, this is a much better solution in my mind because it puts each session on its own record, no need for post-processing. Also it catches the case where someone was only online once, but the session overlapped both time ranges.

Answer (score 2):

Use a self-join. Use column aliases so you can access the columns from each session with different names.

```
SELECT s1.s_calling_station_id, 
    s1.s_session_id AS s1_session_id, s1.s_start_time AS s1_start_time, s1.s_stop_time AS s1_stop_time,
    s2.s_session_id AS s2_session_id, s2.s_start_time AS s2_start_time, s2.s_stop_time AS s2_stop_time
FROM sessions AS s1
JOIN sessions AS s2 
    ON s1.s_calling_station_id = s2.s_calling_station_id 
        AND s1.s_session_id != s2.s_session_id
WHERE   ("2015-10-01 08:00:00" BETWEEN s1.s_start_time AND s1.s_stop_time OR "2015-10-01 08:30:00" BETWEEN s1.s_start_time AND s1.s_stop_time)
    AND
        ("2015-10-01 12:00:00" BETWEEN s2.s_start_time AND s2.s_stop_time OR "2015-10-01 12:30:00" BETWEEN s2.s_start_time AND s2.s_stop_time)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1df471/11)

Comment: Unfortunately this gives the same result as my `GROUP BY` statement (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1df471/3). I actually need the session details for all matching sessions. So I should see details for sessions 4 and 5.

Comment: You do see both details. The details for session 4 are on the left, the details for 5 are on the right.

Comment: Ah, I see. Not ideal but I could work with it. Next question, will this work if there are more than two matching sessions during the time ranges? Doesn't seem like it would.

Comment: It will return a row for each pair.

Comment: So if sessions 1, 2, and 3 are all in the time range, it will return 1-2, 1-3, and 2-3.